# Can I add a custom section to a .vue file

Tags: vue.js

I am using single file Vue components in my app. What I'd like to do is add a new section, . Then, at build time, compile all of these configs into a single config file.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is possible using [Custom Blocks](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/custom-blocks.html#example).